# JSP JSON with Google Charts - Line Charts

Tags: javascript, json, jsp, google-visualization

my graph didn't load up. I try to parse JSON from an JSP page to HTML page with javascript.

I don't know what is the problem. This is the details :

My HTML Page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Google Chart with jsp Mysql Json</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var obj="";
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {

        $.ajax({
            url : 'getDataGlucose.jsp',
            dataType:'json',
            success : function(glucoseData) {
                obj = JSON.stringify(glucoseData)
                alert('Pass? : '+obj);
            },
                error : function(xhr, type) {
                alert('server error occoured')
            }
        });

        var google_data = {
          "cols": [{
              "type": "number"
          }, {
              "type": "number"
          }],
          rows: []
      };

      for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
          google_data.rows.push({
              c: [{
                  v: obj[i].xValue
              }, {
                  v: obj[i].glucose
              }]
          });
      }

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(google_data);

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

            var options = {
                title: 'Glucose Data Intake',
                hAxis: {
                    title: 'Intake'
                },
                curveType: 'function',
                vAxis: {
                    title: 'mmHg'
                }
            };
            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

           chart.draw(data,options);
    }


    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
          <div id="chart_div"></div>
     </body>

    </html>
```

My generate JSON from JSP page :

> [{"glucose":5.5,"xValue":0}, {"glucose":6.2,"xValue":1}, {"glucose":5.8,"xValue":2}, {"glucose":7,"xValue":3}, {"glucose":6,"xValue":4}, {"glucose":7.5,"xValue":5}, {"glucose":6,"xValue":6}, {"glucose":5.5,"xValue":7}, {"glucose":6,"xValue":8}, {"glucose":5.8,"xValue":9}]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found my way out. I changed from :

```
obj = JSON.stringify(glucoseData);
```

to

```
obj = eval('(' + JSON.stringify(glucoseData) + ')');
```

Comment: There is no reason to use eval as you are doing you can use `JSON.parse` to turn the JSON string into an object... But that is moot... `glucoseData` **is already an object** when you get it because of  `dataType: 'json'` so its silly to convert it to a string and then eval it.

Comment: Yeah its working but it should also work with `obj = glucoseData` because its the same thing... You are just converting it to a string (`JSON.stringify(glucoseData)`) and then back to an object again (`eval('(' + JSON.stringify(glucoseData) + ')');`). And you are doing it with `eval` when you could use just use `JSON.parse`.